# text to speech when click on image in my site

Tags: javascript, jquery, text-to-speech

I try to do this text to speech in my site.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DOtkNxmg9QY

i want this text to speech when i click on play(custom1) button in nanogallery2.

this code of nanogallery with pug (home.pug)

```
script(type='text/javascript'src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js')
link(href='https://unpkg.com/nanogallery2/dist/css/nanogallery2.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css')
script(type='text/javascript' src='https://unpkg.com/nanogallery2/dist/jquery.nanogallery2.min.js')

#my_nanogallery2(data-nanogallery2=
{
    "items": categ,
    "itemsBaseURL": "/users/",
    "locationHash": false,
    "thumbnailWidth": "250",
    "thumbnailHeight": "250",
    "thumbnailBorderVertical": 4,
    "thumbnailBorderHorizontal": 4,
    "colorScheme":
    {
        "thumbnail":
        {
            "background": 'rgba(97, 152, 253, 1)',
            "thumbnailIcon" : { "color": '#FFF'}
        }
    },
    "thumbnailLabel":
    {
        "position": "onBottom",
        "titleFontSize": '1.5em'
    },
    "thumbnailAlignment": "center",
    "thumbnailDisplayTransitionDuration": 0,
    "thumbnailDisplayInterval": 3,
    "thumbnailHoverEffect2": null,
    "thumbnailToolbarImage":      { topLeft: 'custom1'},
    "thumbnailToolbarAlbum":      { topLeft: 'custom1'},
    "icons":                      { thumbnailCustomTool1 : '<i  class="fa fa-play-circle" style="font-size:24px"></i>'},
    "fnThumbnailToolCustAction":  SoundCustom,
    "thumbnailOpenImage": false })
```

This options add to my nanogallery a button, when i click the button the "soundcustom" function should work.

```
"thumbnailToolbarImage":      { topLeft: 'custom1'},
"thumbnailToolbarAlbum":      { topLeft: 'custom1'},
"icons":                      { thumbnailCustomTool1 : '<i  class="fa fa-play-circle" style="font-size:24px"></i>'},
"fnThumbnailToolCustAction":  SoundCustom,
```

this is the function "soundcustom" in home.js

```
 function SoundCustom(item){
    console.log(item.title);
    var text;
    text = encodeURIComponent(item.title);
    console.log(text);
    var url = "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=" + text + "&client=tw-ob";
    $('audio').attr('src', url).get(0).play();
}
```

I'm trying to put console logs to see if I get the value. But it turns out I get nothing.

Of course there is no response to pressing the button either.

In addition, when I try to add the script they give in the video it destroys the nanogallery.

I don't know if it's related.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attempts .. The failure was to enter the values ​​to the nanogallery.

"fnThumbnailToolCustAction":  SoundCustom,

To:

"fnThumbnailToolCustAction":  "SoundCustom",

Hope other people don't fall on it.